# When does PL080 DMAC generate error interupt?

Tags: status, dma

DMAC pl080 DMACIntErrorStatus register with register address 0x00C which is a read only register shows the error on the channel by making that particular bit active.
Under what conditions the particular channel bit goes active.

Answer (score 0):

When the slave sends an HRES signal to the master with ERROR response, other HRES can be RETRY, SPLIT or OKAY